# WPF Listview binding not working with Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF Project, in XAML file i have a listview and binding to dictionary. But whenever i change the value of dictionary value it is not binding back to UI. Can anyone help.

My code sample looks like below.

.XAML file:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <Border BorderBrush="SkyBlue" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"></Border>
        <StackPanel>
                <ListView Margin="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="lvAlphaKeys" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding AlphaKeys, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Width="30" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.DispalyName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

View Model:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
         public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
         private Dictionary<string, MyCommand> _AlphaKeys;

        public Dictionary<string, MyCommand> AlphaKeys
        {
            get { return _AlphaKeys; }
            set
            {
                _AlphaKeys = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AlphaKeys"));
            }
        }
}

 public class  MyCommand
    {
        public string DispalyName { get; set; }
        public string DisplaySymbol { get; set; }
    }
```

.XaML.CS FILE:

```
//Field declaration
        MyViewViewModel viewModel;

//Constructur
     viewModel = new MyViewViewModel();
     DataContext = viewModel;   


//Event
    viewModel.AlphaKeys[key].DispalyName = "new value";
```

If i set the itemsource = null and then re assign the Itemsource of list value it is working otherwise not working, can anyone help please?
lvAlphaKeys.ItemSource = null;
lvAlphaKeys..ItemSource = viewModel.AlphaKeys;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the event for `AlphaKeys`, it will raise an event if the collection has changed, not for his item.

You must set `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your `MyCommand`,

```
 public class  MyCommand : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _dispalyName ;
        public string DispalyName 
        {
            get { return _dispalyName ; }
            set
            {
                _dispalyName = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("DispalyName");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyOfPropertyChange(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you mark my answer pls? An upvote will make my day :)

Comment: Done :) Thanks for the Quick help once again